# Replacement for OpenERP PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, odoo

Please let me know whether we can replace OpenERP PostgreSQL database with Oracle or MS SQL ?

If so please provide link /steps to do so. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the reason for replacing Postgres?

Comment: I don't think this is off topic.  For OpenERP it is a valid technical question; "can I replace the DB?"  It doesn't ask "what is a better database to use than postgresql?"

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is No,

Right now OpenERP is using PostgresSQL as a backend.
because the [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)(Object-relational mapping) is based on PostgreSQL 
and a lot of SQL queries in the modules use the PostgreSQL dialect.
There are lots of OpenERP report based on PostgreSQL views.

Comment: Athul, I have come across same query. Is it possible for new customized module of openerp with other database like oracle/ms sql? is there any openerp module which will establish connection between open erp and other database. any suggestion on those lines. thanks

Comment: @shrikanth it is possible to sync db for particular model, There are many Python library available for database connection. Its all about Python.

Comment: Thanks Athul. Please correct me, if I'm wrong here .              This is my understandings-Newly created customized module will be having postgresql as database and it can't be replaced with other database. However using python library we can sync data from postgresql database to other database  like Oracle,MS SQL...etc

Answer (score 0):

As above - the answer is "not without a lot of work".

Ultimately, all queries, whether embedded in code or generated by the ORM end up being a cr.execute.  If you injected your own implementation of the database cursor and had it perform SQL dialect translation on the fly you would get all the python code but you would have to go through reports etc.  OpenERP doesn't actually use a lot of PG specific features, there are no stored procedures for example, so it is theoretically possible I suppose but I imagine you would impose a performance overhead, not to mention the complexity of SQL translation on the fly.

It comes down to the reason; if you have a PHB demanding Oracle you would have to make a call on whether to pursue this or look at Oracle only products.  If you need data warehousing then I would like at ETL products like Pentaho to move data from Postgresql to Oracle or MS SQL.